# How do i change the caption of a label from one form due to answer from a option button in a different form, VBA

Tags: forms, vba

I have an assignment where I am creating a benchmarking tool. The tool requires different forms to pop up depending on which button clicked. 
What i want to do is to have a specific label change from one form based on the option selected from a different form. Below is the code im trying to use. I know that without Form2. ahead of the Yourlabel. I could change a label in current form (form 1) but need it to change caption of label in form 2. I hope this is clear.

```
Private Sub Option1_Click()
Form2.YourLabel.Caption = "Customer Code"
End Sub
```

Any help ?

Comment: add some shots to clarify

Comment: See [UserForms | Best Practices](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/vba/5351/user-forms/19036/best-practices#t=20161208191239786883) on docs.SO; working with the forms' *default instance* is begging for weird bugs to happen later down the road.

Answer (score 0):

Make `Form1` have a public property of type `Form2`:

```
Private otherForm As Form2

Public Property Get TheOtherForm() As Form2
    Set TheOtherForm = otherForm
End Property

Public Property Set TheOtherForm(ByVal value As Form2)
    Set otherForm = value
End Property

Private Sub Option1_Click()
    otherForm.YourLabel.Caption = "Customer Code"
End Sub
```

Now whoever is responsible for bringing up the `Form1` instance, is also responsible for setting the `TheOtherForm` reference:

```
Dim frm1 As Form1
Set frm1 = New Form1

Dim frm2 As Form2
Set frm2 = New Form2

Set frm1.TheOtherForm = frm2
frm1.Show
```

Notice the code is `New`ing up form instances instead of working with the *default instance* of the form type: that way you fully control the objects' lifetimes.

Now, you're coupling `Form1` with whever UI layout you're having on `Form2`. A better idea would be to introduce a little bit of abstraction between the two, by exposing a public procedure on `Form2`:

```
Public Sub SetMyLabelCaption(ByVal value As String)
    YourLabel.Caption = value
End Sub
```

And then the click handler in `Form1` can just call `otherForm.SetMyLabelCaption "CustomerCode"` without caring what the actual label is named, or whether there's even a label at all.

Comment: thank you for your response. I am just a bit lost, where do i stick the dim frm1 as Form1 part? I am fairly new to coding so this is complicated enough for me.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to refer Form Name --> Label Name , Then call the Caption property of Label to change the caption.

Then Load the form, And do a repaint to show the new Caption of label

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    If OptionButton1.Enabled Then
    msgbox "The Caption of your label is going to be changed"
    UserForm2.lbl_frm2.Caption = "The New caption Is here"
    UserForm2.Show
    UserForm2.Repaint
    End If

    End Sub
```